# Finding antiderivative by Maclaurin series

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

I want to find $\int p(x) dx$ where: $$p(x)= \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$

This function can not be manually computed so I am using Maclaurin series to find the antiderivative. I believe the Maclaurin series for this function would be: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\frac{-x^2}{2}^n}{n!}.$$

The bounds of integration would be from $-1$ to $1$. How would I create a Maclaurin series for the antiderivative from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can integrate the Maclaurin Series term by term as follows.
$$2\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\big(\frac{-x^2}{2}\big)^n}{n!}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{0}^1\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{2^nn!}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2^nn!(2n+1)}\Bigg|_{0}^1$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!(2n+1)} \approx 0.682689492$$
From this series, we get an approximation of the true value.

Comment: I have a feeling I made a mistake here. If anyone sees it can they point it out so I can fix it?

Comment: The factor outside should be $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$

Comment: Yep, just fixed it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @IsaacBrowne Wow, brilliantly simple! How many terms would be needed for it to be accurate to four decimal places? I'm not sure how to figure that out without comparing to the actual value.

Comment: Since it is an alternating series, you can look at the first term that is less than $10^{-4}$ in order to be accurate to 4 decimal places. Do you see why? If not, I suggest looking up "alternating series remainder theorem", or attempt to work it out yourself!

Comment: If I'm doing it correctly then it would take 5 terms to get that accuracy because the 5th term is: $$\frac{-1}{42240} \frac{sqrt2}{sqrt pi}$$ and the absolute value of that is less than 0.0001?

Comment: That is a sound argument. Basically, you know your error can't be greater than the 5th term. Thus, here, You will be accurate to within .0001

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is approximate the value of a definite (not indefinite integral, as the Maclaurin series will be useless for this, unless you are satisfied with some other power series and an added constant) using the series you correctly computed.

Using the fact that this is an alternating, you can get a precise bound on the remainder.